# E-Check in USAePay SOAP API

Tags: php, soap, usaepay

I have to make a transaction via USAePay SOAP API.

```
try {
     $Request=array(
              'AccountHolder' => 'Tester Jones',
              'Details' => array(
              'Description' => 'Example Transaction',
              'Amount' => '4.99',
              'Invoice' => '44539'),
              'CheckData' => array(
                            'CheckNumber' => '1234',
                            'Routing' => '123456789',
                            'Account' => '11111111',
                            'AccountType' => 'Savings',
                            'DriversLicense' => '34521343',
                            'DriversLicenseState' => 'CA',
                            'RecordType' => 'PPD'));
return $res=$this->CLIENT->runCheckSale($this->TOKEN, $Request);
}catch (SoapFault $e){
echo $this->CLIENT->__getLastRequest();
echo $this->CLIENT->__getLastResponse();
die("runCheckSale failed :" .$e->getMessage());
}
```

This code is for making check transaction but it's not working. I have created `$client` and `$token`, these are working fine in `addCustomer` and other functions.

Comment: This issue has been solved by rearrange the code and user authentication .